# warning: local declaration of 'mapView' hides instance variable

Tags: iphone, sdk

please, can anybody explain and help me how to fix that warning?? thx in advance.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

        mapRegion=mapView.region; //first warning
    }
    -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated  {

        newRegion=mapView.region; //second warning
        if(mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta>newRegion.span.latitudeDelta||mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta>newRegion.span.longitudeDelta)
            shouldAdjustZoom=NO;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have an instance variable with the name mapView already.

You can change the local name to something else. For example like this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

     mapRegion=aMapView.region; //first warning
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated  {
    newRegion=aMapView.region; //second warning
    if(mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta>newRegion.span.latitudeDelta||mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta>newRegion.span.longitudeDelta)
            shouldAdjustZoom=NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of your MKMapView instance declaration in your interface file, or the name of the local variable in your method.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated...
```