# MKMapView Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I guess error is too strong as it works exactly like I want it to, but I am getting a warning message that is troubling. I am adding a UIViewController to a TabBarController and all I want it to do is display the Map View and then zoom in on the user when the user clicks on that tab.  I built the xib and the only editing I did was to drag an MKMapView over and hook up the outlet, as well as the delegate.  Other than that, this is all the implementation code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc, 250, 250);
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

}
```

The problem is that I am getting a yellow alarm error on the final line that says, "Local declaration of "mapView" hides the instance variable."

However, when I run the app, it seems to be working correctly.  What could this error be referring to?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626885/warning-local-declaration-of-mapview-hides-instance-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you declared your MKMapView object as `mapView`. Look at the method declaration:

`- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView`

it uses the same name as your own variable. This is where the compiler seems to run into a problem. I've had this a couple of times myself now, and my solution was to change my variable name (you could use worldView, for example).

I think you could also solve it with self. Like in other languages, you would use `this.variableName`, I think you can do `self.variableName` to indicate that this one is 'your' variable. If that makes sense?

When I declare my own methods, I usually do like this:

```
 - (void)feedDog:(Dog *)aDog;
```

and then my variable would be called `Dog` to avoid confusion.

Just what I do. If anyone has anything to add to this, feel free to. I'm still fairly new to this, but I did run into this error a couple of times now.

Comment: The compiler isn't having a problem, it is trying to help avoid a coding error by letting you know that the mapView you're getting might not be the one you wanted.  Maybe you intended to reference the mapView instance variable but what you got is the mapView parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```